# How to overlap Label and Data fields over an image in BIRT

Tags: birt

Using BIRT. Added Image in a Grid. Unable to put label and data fields over image in certain region. Please advise if you achieved it.

Thanks,

Yasar

Answer (score 0):

I think all you can do is use the image as background-url. AFAIK this only works for images that actually come from an URL, but not for images that come from e.g. a database BLOB (but you might download the BLOB to a temporary file and use the file name as URL).